# EntityFramework Explicit Loading does not retrieve all entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lazy-loading

I have 2 classes (User and Device) as defined below.

```
public class User {
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Device> Devices { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class Device {
    public int UserId;
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

I have a repository for each one of those two entities and I have disabled lazy loading in my data context like so.

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext()
        : base(name=MyDbContext)
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

**I am trying to retrieve to all devices associated to user account.**

I have tried doing this in 2 different ways.

Approach #1 - Calling Load on the User associated property

```
using (MyDbContext dbContext = new MyDbContext())
{
    // performing some database operations ...

    var user = dbContext.Users.Find(8);

    // do some operations 

    if (user.Devices == null or user.Devices.Count() ==0)
    dbContext.Entry(user).Collection(u => u.Devices).Load();

    var devices = user.Devices;
}
```

Approach #2 - Retrieving from the device set using where

```
using (MyDbContext dbContext = new MyDbContext())
{
    // performing some database operations ...

    var user = dbContext.Users.Find(8);

    // do some operations 

    if (user.Devices == null or user.Devices.Count() ==0)        
    var devices = dbContext.Devices.Where(d => d.UserId == user.UserId).ToList();
}
```

For some reason, approach #1 does not always retrieve all devices however approach #2 retrieves all devices! Can someone please explain me what I am doing wrong?

I started SQL Server Profiler to see whether I was doing something wrong. The queries that were being generated by both approaches were identical. So I am really confused on what I am doing wrong!

Comment: What version of Entity Framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can someone please explain me what I am doing wrong?

I can't explain why you are experiencing what you are experiencing, but I personally don't use `Find()` nor `Load()` as those methods are complicated in terms of how they work with the local context cache.  So I would recommend the following query:

```
var user = dbContext.Users
  .Include(u => u.Devices);
  .FirstOrDefault(u => u.id = 8);
```

Since you are retrieving only a single user there is no [Cartesian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) issues.  This query will populate the context with the user and all devices associated with the user in a single statement.

If you really needed a separate variable with all devices afterwards:

```
var devices = user.Devices;
```

The *important* note about my answer is that because I typically deal with Entity Framework in a web environment, my code constantly creates/disposes of the context so the local cache on Entity Framework is just about useless.  For a non-stateless application (Winforms/WPF) this may not be the best solution.

**Updated Per your Comment**

> Is there any other way of loading at a later time?

As [Brendan Green's Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25626566/entityframework-explicit-loading-does-not-retrieve-all-entities#comment40051654_25627405) mentioned you can use:

```
var devices = dbContext.Devices
  .Where(w => w.UserId == 8);
```

(Please be aware this does not execute the query against the datasource).

Comment: I am new to Entity framework so I am still not completely familiar with different expressions. Does include retrieve all devices whose user id is 8? Or does it retrieve all devices from database and then filters those whose user id is 8?

Comment: the first proposition is true. To convince yourself, use [linqpad](http://www.linqpad.net/)

Comment: @ParthShah I've also updated my answer to be more specific to the question.

Comment: @ErikPhilips i like the answer you have given me but the problem is I don't always need to load devices when  I retrieve a user. (I apologize my code sample is misleading.) Is there any other way of loading at a later time?

Comment: var devices = dbContext.Devices.Where(w => w.UserId == 8)

Comment: @BrendanGreen I have tried that approach already. I was wondering whether that is known to be more reliable than Load()?

Comment: Well, your use of Load() returns all devices, whereas this will only return devices that belong to the given user.

Comment: But I specifically mention load all devices associated to the specified user. dbContext.Entry(user).Collection(u => u.Devices).Load();